# Is CherryPy a robust webserver (ie, is it reliable under a huge load like Apache)?

Tags: python, webserver, cherrypy

I'm wondering because [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/) is, from my knowledge, built purely in Python, which is obviously slower than C et al. Does this mean that it's only good for dev / testing environments, or could I use it behind [NGINX](http://www.nginx.org/) like I use Apache with [Fast CGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/) currently?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

CherryPy's WSGI server is about as fast as a pure-Python WSGI server is going to get.  I personally use it behind Nginx in production, but even standalone on my dev machine I can load each instance with several hundred requests / sec. without problems.

Can you find a faster server? Yes. Is CherryPy a robust web server, and good enough for most people to use in production? Yes.

Comment: Yes, basically it's like this: you can't use it to run something huge like facebook, but you can run your blog on it with no problems

Answer (score 4):

You should probably consider Apache + mod_wsgi as the standard front-end for any Python-based web application.

You do not want to serve any static content (.CSS, .JPEG, etc.) from any Python-based application; you want static files served by Apache.

You want the dynamic HTML page handle separately by the mod_wsgi daemon.

Comment: @S.Lott I usually only serve static files with NGINX (handles quite a bit more concurrent requests than Apache) but I proxy back to Apache with proxy_pass so I can still enjoy the benefits of a keep-alive for a few seconds. I've not tried mod_wsgi though. I'm using Flup and FCGI. I've also tried the trash that is mod_python, pfff. When you scale really big it saves you a ton of resources (but wastes a bit on smaller projects). What are some of the drawbacks of using mod_wsgi, if any?

Comment: @orkuski: CherryPy is already WSGI-compatible.  There's no drawback to mod_wsgi, since it allows you to either plug directly into Apache or run a separate daemon.  Since you're already using a WSGI framework, it simplifies things even further.  Don't proxy back to Apache, use daemon mode and have Apache do all the work for you.